# Bootstrap markdown preview table

Tags: javascript, css, markdown

I use [Bootstrap Markdown](http://www.codingdrama.com/bootstrap-markdown/) on my page,  when I paste table markdown format:

```
| Imię | Nagumo Hajime | Wiek | 17 lat | 
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Płeć | Mężczyzna | Poziom | 49 |
| Klasa | Sztukmistrz Transmutacji (Synergetyk) |
| Siła | 880 | Żywotność | 970 |
| Odporność | 860 | Zręczność | 1040 |
| Magia | 760 | Odporność Magiczna | 760 |
| Umiejętności: |
| - Transmutacja:   
| _\*Szacowanie Minerału _ 
| _\*Precyzyjna Transmutacja_
| _\*Badanie Minerału _
| _\*Oddzielenie Minerału_
| _\*Fuzja Minerału _
| _\*Replikacja Transmutacją_
| - Manipulacja Magią
| - Żelazny Żołądek
| - Powłoka Błyskawic
| - Boski Krok:
| _\*Powietrzny Spacer_
| _\*Migotanie_  
| _\*Potężne Nogi_
| - Noktowizja
|  - Dalekowizja
| - Percepcja
| - Magiczna Percepcja
| - Ukrycie Obecności
| - Powietrzne Szpony
| - Niewrażliwość na Trucizny
| - Niewrażliwość na Paraliż
| - Odporność na Petryfikacje
| - Poznanie Języka |
```

This no rendering in preview, try paste in [editor](http://www.codingdrama.com/bootstrap-markdown/)

When I render on my page it works normal.

How try to fix this, I need css or js or what. Do you have any solution?

Comment: 1) Table markdown for formatted. (2) Changed link to hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

I found this demo http://embed.plnkr.co/atyuBnVNktl8YSfdfPJT/preview
In this preview table work.

When i delete on my code this scripts then table render fine.

```
<script src="/js/markdown.js"></script>
<script src="/js/to-markdown.js"></script>
```

Maybe it will help someone :)